# Как осуществить динамический подсчет в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Создаю редактируемую таблицу подсчета стоимости товара и хочу сделать динамический подсчет значения двух ячеек. Как это сделать?

```js
function x1(x, y, z) {
  var x = $('#' + x).text();
  var y = $('#' + y).text();
  $('#' + z).text(x * y);
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,th {
  border: 1px solid #aac;
  padding: 0;
}

td p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

td p:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #5D90FE;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<table id="example" contenteditable="true">
  <tr contenteditable="false"> <th>Номер</th> <th>Название</th> <th>Цена</th><th>Количество</th><th>Сумма</th> </tr>
  <tr> <td>1</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x1">0</td>  <td id="y1">2</td> <td id="sum1">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x1','y1','sum1')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>2</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x2">0</td>  <td id="y2">2</td> <td id="sum2">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x2','y2','sum2')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>3</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x3">0</td>  <td id="y3">2</td> <td id="sum3">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x3','y3','sum3')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>4</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x4">0</td>  <td id="y4">2</td> <td id="sum4">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x4','y4','sum4')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>5</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x5">0</td>  <td id="y5">2</td> <td id="sum5">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x5','y5','sum5')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>6</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x6">0</td>  <td id="y6">2</td> <td id="sum6">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x6','y6','sum6')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>7</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x7">0</td>  <td id="y7">2</td> <td id="sum7">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x1','y1','sum7')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>8</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x8">0</td>  <td id="y8">2</td> <td id="sum8">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x1','y1','sum8')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>9</td> <td>Название</td> <td id="x9">0</td>  <td id="y9">2</td> <td id="sum9">0</td> <td><button onclick="x1('x1','y1','sum9')"  contenteditable="false">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Тут и девчата есть, by the way.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "динамическим подсчетом"?

Comment: Ну, что бы данные считывались и сразу после ввода же выводился результат умножения.

Comment: А вот это кошмарное `onclick="x1('x1','y1','sum9')"` (включая опечатки в `x9` и `y9`) вас не беспокоит?

Comment: Это черновой вариант, я собираюсь добавить другое, мне просто нужно понять куда идти дальше,что бы сделать динамический подсчет, я понимаю, что тут куча опечаток ну все же)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Делаем `contenteditable="true"` непосредственно на необходимых `td`
2. Меняем `id` у `td` на `class`
3. Добавляем обработчик события `input` для ячеек количества и цены
4. В этом обработчике считаем сумму и выводим в соответствующий `td`

Итоговый код:

```js
$(".price,.count").on("input", function() {
  var $elements = $(this).siblings().addBack();
  var $price = $elements.filter(".price");
  var $count = $elements.filter(".count");
  var $sum = $elements.filter(".sum");
  $sum.text($price.text() * $count.text());
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,th {
  border: 1px solid #aac;
  padding: 0;
}

td p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

td p:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #5D90FE;
}
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr> <th>Номер</th> <th>Название</th> <th>Цена</th><th>Количество</th><th>Сумма</th> </tr>
  <tr> <td>1</td> <td>Название</td> <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>  <td contenteditable="true" class="count">2</td> <td contenteditable="true" class="sum">0</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>2</td> <td>Название</td> <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>  <td  contenteditable="true"class="count">2</td> <td class="sum">0</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>3</td> <td>Название</td> <td contenteditable="true" class="price">0</td>  <td contenteditable="true" class="count">2</td> <td class="sum">0</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

1. Если код скрипта находится на странице выше таблицы, то нужно не забыть про обработку `document.ready`:

   ```
   $(function() {
       //основной код
   });
   ```
2. Вместо `siblings().addBack()` + `filter` можно отталкиваться от `tr` + использовать `find` вместо `filter`